# What will the output of a system which has no Fourier transform?

Tags: signal-analysis, fourier-transform, continuous-signals, laplace-transform

Let's assume a system $h(t)= e^{j2t}$. This system has no region of convergence. What will be the output if I provide any input to this system?

Comment: ROC is a term used in Laplace transform and Z transform, not for Fourier transform. If a signal is absolutely integrable, then its Fourier transform exists. https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/53875/can-a-fourier-transform-exist-even-if-the-j-omega-axis-is-not-in-the-region-of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does have a Fourier transform. The Fourier transform of $h(t)=e^{j2t}$ is given by

$$H(j\omega)=2\pi\delta(\omega-2)\tag{1}$$

You are right that you can't treat that system with the Laplace transform.

A system with frequency response $(1)$ is not bounded-input-bounded-output (BIBO) stable, i.e., there are bounded input signal for which the output is unbounded.

You can compute the output for a given input using the convolution integral:

$$\begin{align}y(t)&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(\tau)e^{2j(t-\tau)}d\tau\\&=e^{2jt}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(\tau)e^{-2j\tau}d\tau\\&=e^{2jt}X(j2)\tag{2}\end{align}$$

where $X(j\omega)$ is the Fourier transform of the input signal $x(t)$, assuming that the integral in $(2)$ exists.

From $(2)$ we see that all input signals with a finite Fourier transform at $\omega=2$ will result in an output signal that is just a scaled version of the system's impulse response.